# Why was this harmless looking question marked as spam/RA and deleted (by a moderator)?

Tags: discussion, spam, rude-or-abusive

Why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76826703/rust-how-to-convert-a-base64-string-to-a-hex-string) marked as spam or RA and deleted by a moderator?

Screenshot for those who can't see deleted posts:
[image]

It's certainly not a quality question and already got a close vote and there was a later self-deleted answer (from a different user) that was maybe AI-generated, but that seems to be unrelated to the flag and deletion.

There are no links in the question, no product mentioned, and nothing rude, and even the shown Base64 seems to be just binary data.
There is nothing in the question that indicates that it is spam or rude/abusive. The question is also on-topic on SO.

As far as I know/have seen, moderators delete questions only if they are either actually spam/RA or off-topic (including being asked in other languages than English). In the latter case, they would usually close the question first.

None of the known (to me) reasons applies here. So what is the reason.

And of course, I'm aware that
a) only the person who flagged can actually tell why they flagged,
b) humans make mistakes, and this could be the answer.

Comment: My immediate suspicion is that the user may have been sockpuppeting, to circumvent a question ban, suspension, or some other restriction. Mods have ways of telling if that's happening and will delete any such posts (and often the sockpuppet account as well, though apparently not in this case).

Comment: Note: While the specific thing you asked about, why that question appears to be marked as spam or rude/abusive, is covered by the duplicate this question is now close against, there's at least one closely associated question, "why was that question deleted?", which isn't covered by the duplicate, but you didn't ask that question, so it's not answered here (but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be asked).

Comment: Based on the linked duplicate, what seems to have happened was: 1. Someone red flagged it as spam 2.Moderator deleted that post due to any reason(not necessarily spam), which caused spam red-flag to auto apply.  Due to the specificity of the question, I  think this should be reopened. As Makyen points out: `why was that question deleted`, that question becomes the main question, as that question deletion is the direct cause of spam flag auto application. It is possible that it maybe a mistake on the part of the moderator to delete the question instead of the answer, which was marked chatGPT.

Comment: @TheMaster I disagree that this question should be reopened *in its current form*. In its current form, this question is, IMO, definitely a duplicate. That doesn't mean there isn't a different question which could be asked about the same SO main question. Given that there's no answer here and that it was quickly closed as a duplicate, I don't, personally, have a problem if the asker wants to edit it to ask the "why deleted" question instead. However, it's quite clear, IMO, what was actually asked, so I don't feel it appropriate for the question to be changed so significantly by someone else.

Comment: @Makyen I am inclined to agree but isn't this  completely hypothetical? How do we know for sure that the moderator didn't see the spam flag and vote to delete it, in a attempt to mark the spam flag as helpful or marked the flag as helpful and then proceed to delete the question? The other scenario that the duplicate potrays is moderator deleted it without paying explicit attention to the spam flag. While that scenario is entirely possible, how exactly do we know that, that is exactly what happened in this case? I don't know the intricacies of moderation,[1/2]

Comment: ..so If I missed any obvious signs(that are public) to differentiate, let me know[2/2].

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the feedback. I reworded the question and included the "why was it deleted" part.

Comment: question had large wall of text as base64, was poorly formatted & worded, plus was attracting chatgpt spam answers. I deleted the question as a quick response. Now edited & undeleted, also cleared spamflag

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for the response and explanation. I totally agree regarding the quality or lack thereof but *was attracting chatgpt spam answers* could nowadays be said about tons of questions, IMHO no reason to punish the OP for that.

Comment: @jps - Unless that was the entire point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question had large wall of text as base64, was poorly formatted & worded, plus was starting to attract chatgpt spam answers.

I deleted the question as a quick response, with no intention to "punish" the OP.

Now edited & undeleted, nuked spam answer, and also cleared spamflag.

It may have a rust duplicate somewhere though, as it's very basic (the main reason it attracted chatgpt answers by the way).

Comment: I searched for duplicates. A few similar questions are out there, but given the trivial nature of "just use the crate `base64`", these ones either mention it as part of the MRE for another problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233753) or mention several other things, losing focus in the process (https://stackoverflow.com/q/26572015).

Comment: rust is relatively "new", that must explain it

Comment: 8 years since official release... I guess compared to the giants that is still pretty wet behind the ears. But 8 years and no question about how to do base64 conversions? The documentation must be really good.

Comment: or people who tried the language hung themselves out of boredom

Comment: PainError caused by: HotTeaInLapException.